# One field set which contains every field from All objects

Tags: fieldsets, dynamic

Question for you knowledgable salesforce people

Aim- to create one field set , which holds all fields from every object, and dynamically populate the field sets when new fields add to the object

I know you can create feld sets manually per object, but that's not efficient or effective for what I'm trying to achieve

Looking forward to your response

Comment: You can't do this since fieldsets are scoped to one object. Here is a good blog post for an all fields describe: http://blog.shivanathd.com/2013/10/describe-all-fields-for-all-sobjects.html

Comment: I have created an object which references a field set which I have created for the account object. The object has a trigger and lists when the field was last modified( I couldn't use field history tracking before anyone suggests it).so the aim is to create a field set which all field from all objects go and the trigger will continue to work

Comment: Triggers don't execute globally, either, so you'd have to make one trigger per object anyways.

Comment: Hmm I don't really want to create multiple triggers for the different objects . Hmm